# D3 Pie Chart json Structure issue?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I wanted to create a simple pie chart from a json feed however after following a few examples I am at a point where firebug is not giving me any errors,yet there is not pie chart showing up. Im not sure if it has something to do with my json structure? I was getting a error like this for a while :

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'map'
```

Below is my code:

```
<script>
   function init(){
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
var r = h/2;
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5","#8a89a6","#7b6888","#6b486b","#a05d56","#d0743c"]);                      

var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'ceigis' });
    sql.execute("SELECT status, COUNT(status) FROM deldot_rail_crossing GROUP BY status")
        .done(function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.total_rows; i++) {
                    var filterdata = data.rows[i];
            }

var chart = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(filterdata)   
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")    

var arc = d3.svg.arc()            
    .outerRadius(r);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()         
    .value(function(d) { return d.count; });

 var arcs = chart.selectAll("g.slice")     
    .data(pie)                           
    .enter()                            
        .append("svg:g")               
            .attr("class", "slice");

    arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) 
            .attr("d", arc);                                     

    arcs.append("svg:text")                                     
            .attr("transform", function(d) {                   
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = r;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";       
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")                          
        .text(function(d, i) { return filterdata.rows[i].status; });        

    })   

  .error(function(errors) {
    // do nothing
  })

}

    </script>
   </head>
  <body onload="init()">
 </body>
</html>
```

And below is what my json query is returning:

```
{"time":0.005,"fields":{"status":{"type":"string"},"count":{"type":"number"}},
"total_rows":4,"rows":[{"status":"private","count":169},{"status":"comp","count":41},
 {"status":"not_comp","count":276},{"status":"pre_qaqc","count":10}]}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `filterdata` is an object, you should pass an array to the `data` method. If you use `.selectAll("svg").data([filterdata])`, you need to append the element on `enter`:

```
var chart = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data([filterdata])
    .enter()
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
```

D3 expects that the argumetn of `data` to be an array. The `filterdata` object don't have a `map` method, and thus the error. You can also bind a single object to a selection, but you need to append it first:

```
var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .datum(filterdata)
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you @Pablo Navarro,but If i try the following i get the same error back again? Is there some other part of my code interfering with the array?

Comment: There are some more problems in your code. For one thing, you probably want to do `filterdata = data.rows`, instead of assigning each row to the variable `filterdata`. Then, the `pie` layout is a function, you need to invoke it passing an array to it (`.data(pie(filterdata))`). I recommend to comment to verify that `filterdata` is what you think it is, and then go step by step adding the SVG and the pie chart. Regards,

Comment: thank you for your patience and help. You set me on the right path and helped me realize that I was trying to pass object instead of an array.